# How do I customise the border and background color of my matplotlib-venn plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, matplotlib-venn

I'm trying to customise the figure area of a [venn plot](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib-venn/) using the plt.figure method, but can't get the expected results.

I'm trying to create a black border and a white background on the plot, but the image still comes out transparent without a border.

I suspect I'm missing something basic with my code, but any pointers would be appreciated. Here's my code.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn2, venn2_circles 

# Call 2 group Venn diagram
v = venn2(subsets = (10, 0, 5), set_labels = ('Euler', 'Venn'))
c = venn2_circles(subsets=(10,0,5), linestyle='dashed')

# Format
c[0].set_lw(2.0)
c[0].set_ls('dotted')
c[0].set_alpha(1)
c[0].set_color('#a6cee3')
c[1].set_lw(2.0)
c[1].set_ls('dotted')
c[1].set_alpha(1)
c[1].set_color('#b2df8a')

# Labels
plt.title("Diagrams")
for idx, subset in enumerate(v.subset_labels):
    v.subset_labels[idx].set_visible(False)

# Figure
plt.figure(linewidth=10, edgecolor="black", facecolor="white")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`plt.figure()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) before you call any drawing function. So, before calling  `v = venn2(...`.

`plt.figure()` creates a new area to draw or plot something on, and can handle a lot of options. If you don't call `plt.figure()` or some equivalent function, matplotlib creates a default `figure`. And when you call `plt.figure()` later on, matplotlib starts a new empty `figure`. Normally, matplotlib will show you two windows: the first with the default `figure` settings, and the second without a plot.

The complete example, a bit rewritten to make use of loops, would look like:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn2, venn2_circles


plt.figure(linewidth=10, edgecolor="black", facecolor="white")

# Call 2 group Venn diagram
v = venn2(subsets=(10, 0, 5), set_labels=('Euler', 'Venn'))
circles = venn2_circles(subsets=(10, 0, 5), linestyle='dashed')

# circle format
for circle, color in zip(circles, ['#a6cee3', '#b2df8a']):
    circle.set_lw(2.0)
    circle.set_ls('dotted')
    circle.set_alpha(1)
    circle.set_color(color)

# hide unwanted labels
for label in v.subset_labels:
    label.set_visible(False)

plt.title("Diagrams")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Now that I have the plt item working, I've got more to play with. Thank you for your answer, and the bonus more pythonic formatting of the circles.